# Getting 400 from Axios Post request

Tags: c#, reactjs, axios

I have a dotnet core webapi backend and on front end react typescript. I have one endpoint in which I create a user, but when I am submitting a response, I get 400 bad request errors on the browser console. For detail, I saw in the network tab it's saying: `errors: {Name: ["The Name field is required."]}`

Here is my Axios post request:

```
const res = await axios.post(
            `$localhost:5000/api/User`, {
              body: {Name: "test", Username: "testuser" },
              headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          }
```

on back-end

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Post([FromBody] UserDto dto)
{

}
```

UserDto contains three properties one "Age" is optional two are required "Name" and "Username"

the same request use Post man is working but not working through `Axios`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://axios-http.com/docs/api_intro), when using the alias methods `url`, `method`, and `data` properties don't need to be specified in config.

Please try

```
axios.post(
  `$localhost:5000/api/User`, // url
  { Name: "test", Username: "testuser" }, // data or body
  {
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } // config
  }
)
```

Comment: same error with ```data```

Comment: @SagharFrancis updated answer, can you try.

Answer (score 0):

```
// send a POST request
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/login',
  data: {
    firstName: 'Finn',
    lastName: 'Williams'
  }
});
```

[Axios will automatically convert the data to JSON and send it as the request body.](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-make-http-requests-like-a-pro-with-axios/#:%7E:text=Axios%20will%20automatically%20convert%20the%20data%20to%20JSON%20and%20send%20it%20as%20the%20request%20body.)